# Solarized theme in OS X Terminal having brighter font colors compared to Vim

Tags: vim, terminal, osx-yosemite, color-scheme

I have imported a [Solarized theme for OS X Terminal](https://github.com/tomislav/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized) created by Tomislav Filipčić (this is a port of Solarized for OS X 10.7+ terminals). I'm having a weird issue there. Font colors in the shell seem to be brighter than they should be in Solarized (they look washed-out), but colors in terminal Vim are fine (i also use Solarized for Vim, with no additional settings at all - just `colorscheme solarized`).

Below is the screenshot comparing shell font color and Vim color across different Tmux panes:

[image]

According to Tomislav [(github issue)](https://github.com/tomislav/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/issues/11), it is due to some color adjustment methods that Terminal employs.

I've also noticed that if `Display ANSI colors` checkbox is unchecked in Terminal Preferences, all colors, including the ones in Vim, become pale as in shell. Is there any way this issue can be addressed?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29487/is-it-possible-to-disable-terminals-automatic-tweaking-of-colors-in-lion

Comment: @Stefan - I did not remotely imagine the degree of nuance this entails. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching to a different [Solarized theme by Tayler Mulligan](https://github.com/tamul/solarized-osx-terminal-colors) worked great. Now I do get proper colors, both in shell and Vim. I compared sRGB colour values against MacVim using OS X's Digital Color Meter, all values are identical. This solves the issue.

Comment: Cheers mate! You made my life way better.